# Let $V \in \mathscr{B}$, is there a balanced set $U$ belonging to the family $\mathscr{B}$ contained in $V$?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, filters

Let $E$ be a vector space over the filed of complex numbers. Suppose that $E$ is the union of an increasing sequence ($E_n \subset E_{n+1}$) of subspaces $E_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that on each $E_n$ there is a structure of Fréchet space such that the natural injection of $E_n$ in $$E_{n+1}$ is an isomorphism.

Let
$$\mathscr{B}=\{V\subset E: V \hbox{ is convex }, V \cap E_n \in \mathscr{F}_{E_n}(0) \hbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}\},$$
where $\mathscr{F}_{E_n}(0)$ denotes the filter of neighborhooods of the origin in $E_n$.

**My question**: Let $V$  be a element of the family $\mathscr{B}$. Is there a balanced set $U$ belonging to the family $\mathscr{B}$ contained in $V$? Or are there spaces that do not fulfill this condition, in this case, what would be a counterexample?

The only thing I could think of was: Let $V \in \mathscr{B}$, since $V\cap E_n \in \mathscr{F}_{E_n}(0)$,  for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a balanced set (which we can assume convex) such that $U_n \in \mathscr{F}_{E_n}(0)$ such that $U_n \subset V\cap E_n\subset V$, but I don't know how to build a set $U$ satisfying the desired properties from tha family $\{U_n\}$.

Comment: If all $U_n$ are balanced and convex (which you can assume) isn't the convex hull of the union still balanced?

Comment: Is there any way to guarantee $U \cap E_n \in \mathscr{F}_{E_n(0)}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Where $U=\hbox{ convex hull of } \bigcup U_n$. This question arose from the following fact:In the book of Trèves, he does not assume that the base of the filter of neighborhoods of 0 in the inductive limit topology is formed by balanced sets and without this I was unable to prove the subsequent results. On the other hand, in Yosida's book, he assumes that the sets are balanced.

Comment: Every topological vector space has a basis of balanced $0$-neighbourhoods. This is a consequence of the continuity of the multiplication.